# Docker daemon using several registries

Tags: docker, daemon

In my platform, I want to configure a local registry for *Docker* and configure my *Docker* daemon to use it as the main option, but, for example, if this registry is down, a hypothetical docker pull command will be attempted by the *Docker Hub* as a fallback mechanism. Is it possible?

Example:

```
image -> myimage:0.1
```

The image already exists in the *DockerHub* and also in my *LocalRegistry*.

From my server, I run: `docker pull myimage:0.1`, but I want this request will be attended by the *LocalRegistry* automatically. And, if it fails, the `pull` will be attended from the *DockerHub*.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks. I think that I need the mirror registry option: https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/#run-a-registry-as-a-pull-through-cache

I'm trying with that.

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved this using the registry in proxy mode (mirror) and configuring the docker daemon with "registry-mirrors".

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/#run-a-registry-as-a-pull-through-cache